# Batch compare middle portion of two file's names to do something if they are different

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, compare

I am trying to isolate a version number in an ipsw filename.

The code another submitted here below works well, but it does not work for:
iPhone_5.5_P3_14.1_18A8395_Restore

I need to isolate the "14.1" without accidentally isolating the "5.5".

Comment: It appears you have too many parts to your post, so your question is currently too broad for assistance within the guidelines. Please use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64546551/edit), to improve it, using the advice from reading [ask], and each of its linked pages. Whilst you do that, take a look at my post in the answer area, _(I may delete it later, as it is not technically an answer)_, which attempts to show you how you can split up the filenames for potentially modifying one or more parts of each.

Comment: If you want to copy / sync files, take a look at the `RoboCopy` command. To find out how to use it, open a Command Prompt window, _(`cmd`)_, type `help robocopy`, and press the `ENTER]` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information in your opening paragraph suggests that you've not found examples of searching a directory for files with a pattern/glob and isolating a section of it. IMO, this has been covered thousands of times on this site, under the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag alone. However, here's some example code to assist you.

Please remember to adjust the path, `%AppData%\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`, on line `2` first, if I've guessed it incorrectly.

```bsh
@For /F Tokens^=1-4^ Delims^=_^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D^
 "%AppData%\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates\iPhone*,?_*.?.?_*_Restore.ipsw"'
) Do @For /F Tokens^=1-3^ Delims^=.^ EOL^= %%K In ("%%H") Do @Echo Token1=%%G:Token2=%%H^
:NestedToken1=%%K:NestedToken2=%%L:NestedToken3=%%M^
:Token3=%%I:Token4=%%J^
:Token4Name=%%~nJ:Token4Extension=%%~xJ
@Pause
```

You can also have it as a single, *difficult to read*, line, if you prefer:

```bsh
@(For /F Tokens^=1-4^ Delims^=_^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "%AppData%\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates\iPhone*,?_*.?.?_*_Restore.ipsw"') Do @For /F Tokens^=1-3^ Delims^=.^ EOL^= %%K In ("%%H") Do @Echo Token1=%%G:Token2=%%H:NestedToken1=%%K:NestedToken2=%%L:NestedToken3=%%M:Token3=%%I:Token4=%%J:Token4Name=%%~nJ:Token4Extension=%%~xJ)&Pause
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works quite well, with the exception of ipsw filenames that contain "." before the version number is shown, in which case it shows, for example, "5.5" in iPhone_5.5_P3_14.1_18A8395_Restore, but does not show "14.1".

Comment: Well it shouldn't! First of all the glob I used, `iPhone*,?_*.?.?_*_Restore.ipsw` doesn't match your now completely changed example file pattern, `iPhone_5.5_P3_14.1_18A8395_Restore`, which I believe was `iPhone13,3_14.0.1_18A8395_Restore`. Because you've changed your pattern, you'll need to change the glob, the tokens, and delimiters as needed. I'm not in the habit of modifying my answers after posting them, just because the question changed. The whole reason I posted this as an answer was so that you'd understand how to use tokens and delimiters to split a string to suit your purpose.